# Mega Menu for Joomla / Drupal

Tags: drupal, joomla, megamenu

Any idea on `Megamenu`nowadays used frequently on different websites for menu display purpose.

We want to use the same in Joomla / Drupal, your suggestions would be appreciated !

Thanks,

Comment: there is plenty of documentation on each respective website and the ability to search for their plugins.  Your question is relatively unclear (are you wanting links to downloads?  Do you want particular plugin suggestions that use Megamenu? What exactly do you want that google couldn't provide?)

Comment: @Hanny: though i thought to ask community if they had such type of menu used & having more clarity about... Its never too late to ask someone for more ideas :)

Comment: True!  More ideas are always good - just using a touch more clarity in the question would have helped invoke a few more answers.  Happy MegaMenu'ing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really unclear what you're asking but both CMSs that you mention support the Mega Menu plugin.

These are the respective links to drop-in modules that will add Mega Menu to your Drupal/Joomla site:

[Mega Menu for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/megamenu)
[Mega Menu for Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/18101)